# Can ng-model be used as a directive attribute without binding to a template <input>?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to use `ng-model` in a directive (with `NgModelController`) without binding it to an `<input>` tag which is the template markup set to replace the directive markup?

**
Edit - here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnunamak/b3RAx/) with desired functionality, except for the `span` wrapping the template

If I were granted a wish, I would wish to define a directive like this:

```
<multi-component-zip ng-model='address.zipCode' size="10"/>
```

where the `multi-component-zip` directive is defined with properties:

```
template: '<input ng-model="collapsedZip" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$/" type="text" />', 
replace: true,
require: 'ngModel'
```

The template `ng-model` here would be treated separately from the directive's own.

I'd like to use `collapsedZip` within the directive to modify the value of `address.zipCode` which looks like: `{base: '90210', plusFour: '1234'}` via `NgModelController`.

But, of course, in reality ng-model from the parent is applied to the `<input>` so I get an error:

```
Multiple directives [ngModel, ngModel] asking for 'ngModel' controller on: <input ng-model="address.zipCode collapsedZip" ... >
```

And maybe another approach would be to avoid using ng-model for `collapsedZip`, and instead do direct DOM manipulation on the input element to read/display the user's input.

That's fine, except the `ng-model` attribute is still inherited from the parent tag and defeats the purpose of the directive because it binds to the `<input>`.

So why not wrap the `template` `<input>` with another element, like a `<span>`? This would separate the two `ng-model`'s rather well. Well, other `<input>` attributes like `size=10` should be inherited.

Instead of `ng-model` to bind data to the directive I can use a custom attribute and use watch expressions or another method to synchronize `address.zipCode` with `collapsedZip`. That works. But if I can use `ng-model` it would make life a little easier with some other directives I've written for validation.

Comment: If you bind the ng-model attribute via the directive's scope: entry, does it take precedence over the existing behavior? I think you want something like "scope: collapsedZip:'=ngModel'". That would usually work, but I'm not sure whether it or the handling of the ng-model directive will take precedence. (You could avoid that by using a name other than ng-model, of course...)

Comment: I think (?) regardless of how I define the scope, the template inherits all of the markup attributes, including `ng-model="address.zipCode"` so now the template definition has `ng-model="address.zipCode collapsedZip"` which is not allowed.


But more importantly I don't want `collapsedZip` to be bound to the (inherited?) `ng-model="address.zipCode"`. In fact, if I can get away without binding it with any `ng-model` that is just fine. I can just use manual DOM manipulation for mapping between `address.zipCode` and `collapsedZip`.